Восстановление SQL базы mdf
База в формате mdf через команду
CREATE   DATABASE "name" ON
(
    FILENAME=N'X:\Base\name.mdf')

FOR ATTACH_FORCE_REBUILD_LOG
GO

база не восстанавливается, как можно восстановить?
Ошибка -
Сообщение 5172, уровень 16, состояние 2, строка 1
Заголовок файла "X:\Base\MS-KhachatrenA-Trade.mdf" не является действительным заголовком файла базы данных. Свойство FILEID неверно.
Сообщение 1802, уровень 16, состояние 7, строка 1
Ошибка операции CREATE DATABASE. Некоторые из перечисленных имен файлов не были созданы. Проверьте связанные ошибки.
